# how to instruct ngram parser of mysql not cut number

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to use mysql fulltext search for japanese.

I learned that because there is no space in japanese so ngram would tokenize by cut the string by length (“ab cd” is parsed to “ab”, “cd”). And by so "123" would by tokenize into "12" and "23".

But i don't want it to work like that. I want it to keep number as it is ("123" is still "123").

I have been tried to read ngram setting in mysql and found only setting is **ngram_token_size**.
But this setting won't work in my case.

Is there anyway i can achieve my goal?